# Input class not found in laravel 5

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to save file uploaded through form into a json file for this I need to get post data which is easily get through Request or Input class methods.

The problem is whenever I use Request or Input I can't get methods such as getClientOriginalName to get name of file and other parameters of file.

My FileController code is as below:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;            // this handles both for Input and Request as in laravel 5.1 documentation
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;   // though added some classes to get work
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;    // though added some classes to get work
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;   // though added some classes to get work

class FileController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $files = $this->getAllData();
    return view('document.index', compact('files'));
}


public function create()
{
    return view('document.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $name = $request->input('title');

    echo $name;

    $file = $request->file('afile');

    if($request->hasFile('afile')) {

        $file = $request->file('afile');

        print_r($file); // return array of uploaded as expected

        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // not working

        // or 

        $filename = Input::file('afile')->getClientOriginalName(); // not working

        echo $filename;
    }

    // print_r($file);

    // $data= array('title'=>$name, 'afile'=>$file);

    // $this->create_entry($data);

    // return redirect('document');
}
}
```

FYI my file upload is sucessful and has got file array as

```
Array ( [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => new_file_1.txt [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => text/plain [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => E:\xampp\tmp\php5680.tmp [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php5680.tmp ) )
```

The only problem is I can't get methods of [Symphon2 API](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) though i used

```
use Input;
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Every methods of **Input** are not working either to check its valid or not.

Every tutorial I refer or documentation from laravel 5 uses same as I have used in my code. 
So any Kind of suggestion or solution is really appreciated.

the functions as used in [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#basic-request-information) documentation are working but no other methods except than that.

Comment: Please do dd($request->file('afile')); It seems it is null

Comment: try adding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input` into your use statements

Comment: the array of afile is :
Array ( [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => new_file_11.txt [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => text/plain [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => E:\xampp\tmp\php2B0C.tmp [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php2B0C.tmp ) )

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the use statement for the Input facade. Add the following to your use statements.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Comment: Still getting error::
FatalErrorException in FileController.php line 36:
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Since you have already used the following:

```
$file = $request->file('afile');
```

The `file` method returns an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` and in this case, the instance is already cached in the `$file` variable.

Also to make sure the upload was successful you may check it using something like this:

```
if($request->hasFile('afile')) {

    $file = $request->file('afile');

    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName() .'.'. $file->getExtension();
}
```

Comment: $request->hasFile('afile') returns true but the line 

    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getExtension();

still not working

Comment: this api http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

is not intregrating in my laravel 5. I have this file in my vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
\Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Than for sure your file is not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

In your form open tag add `'files' => true`

```
{!! Form::open(array('files' => true, ....)) !!}
```

In the controller check first if the file has been uploaded correctly

```
if (!Input::file('afile')->isValid())
{
    // return error 50x
}

$filename = Input::file('afile')->getClientOriginalName();
```

*can't apply method to non-object* means that Input::file(...) returned null and therefore the file wasn't uploaded or it doesn't exists. Then, when you call `->getClientOriginalName()` from a null value php throws an exception.

Comment: the code 
     Input::file('afile')->isValid() 
is itself not working

Comment: i have that too still not working.
Is there bug in laravel5 about this, or may be some minor mistakes in my code where my eyes haven't get yet.